# If a structure has a definable ordered pairing function, must it have a definable unordered pairing function, and vice versa?

Tags: model-theory

Is there a structure $M$ with a definable ordered pair function, but no definable unordered pair function? Also, is there a structure $M$ with a definable unordered pair function, but no definable ordered pair function?

Comment: I think you need to say a bit about what you mean by an "ordered pair function" and an "unordered pair function".

Comment: Trivial observation for the first question: if a structure eliminates imaginaries then an ordered pair function will give an unordered pair function. It is easy to define an equivalence relation on the ordered pairs such that the equivalence classes become unordered pairs (the exact implementation might depend on your answer to Peter's comment).

Comment: Finally got a full answer (well, Fedor Pakhomov did :P)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a surprisingly tricky question! The short version is that **unordered pairs always yield ordered pairs but not conversely**. To keep things precise, given a structure $\mathcal{A}$ say that:

- $\mathcal{A}$ **has a pairing function** iff there is a formula $\varphi(x,y,z)$ with parameters from $\mathcal{A}$ such that $$\mathcal{A}\models\forall x,y\exists!z\varphi(x,y,z)\wedge \forall x,y,x',y',z(\varphi(x,y,z)\wedge\varphi(x',y',z)\leftrightarrow x=x'\wedge y=y'),$$ and
- $\mathcal{A}$ **has an unordered pairing function** iff there is a formula $\varphi(x,y,z)$ with parameters from $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying the same condition but with the clause $x=x'\wedge y=y'$ replaced by $(x=x'\wedge y=y')\vee (x=y'\wedge y=x')$.

The first thing to observe is that any of the usual set-theoretic definitions of ordered pairing functions (e.g. Kuratowski) yield the following:

> **Fact 1:** If $\mathcal{M}$ has a definable unordered pairing function, then $\mathcal{M}$ has a definable ordered pairing function.

*Proof:* If $f:\mathcal{M}^2\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$ is a definable unordered pairing function, consider the new function $$f_{Kur}:(a,b)\mapsto f(f(a,b),f(a,a)).$$ This basically implements the Kuratowski ordered pair. $\quad\Box$

Getting *rid* of order turns out to be harder. In fact, it's **impossible** in general!

> **Fact 3**: There is a structure $\mathcal{M}$ which has a definable ordered pairing function but has no definable unordered pairing function.

This was pointed out to me by [Fedor Pakhomov at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428845/8133), and is a consequence of a quantifier elimination theorem of Mal'tsev.

That said, there are nontrivial "strength criteria" on structures which ensure that pairing functions can always be de-orderd. Most obviously, we have the following:

> **Fact 3:** Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ has a definable linear order (with domain all of $\mathcal{M}$ itself). Then if $\mathcal{M}$ has a definable ordered pairing function, it also has a definable unordered pairing function.

*Proof:* If $\trianglelefteq$ is a definable linear order on $\mathcal{M}$ and $f$ is a definable ordered pairing function on $\mathcal{M}$, consider the function $$g(a,b)=\begin{cases}
f(a,b) & \mbox{ if } a\trianglelefteq b\\
f(b,a) & \mbox{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$ This has the desired property. $\quad\Box$

More generally, it's enough for $\mathcal{M}$ to have a definable *tournament* - that is, a definable map $t:\mathcal{M}^2\rightarrow\mathcal{M}$ with $t(a,b)=t(b,a)\in\{a,b\}$ for all $a,b\in\mathcal{M}$. A linear order yields this via "pick the least." Interestingly, even a tournament is overkill: [James Hanson observed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4435439/28111) that there are "base structures" which have no definable ordered pairing function, *do* have enough power to definably "de-order" an auxiliary ordered pairing function, but don't have a definable tournament. This paragraph constitutes, in my opinion, a respectable **Fact 4** on which to end.