# Are there structures that "nontrivially" let us convert ordered pairing functions to unordered pairing functions?

Tags: logic, model-theory

*This question is an outgrowth of my partial answer to [this older MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221319/if-a-structure-has-a-definable-ordered-pairing-function-must-it-have-a-definabl). Throughout, formulas are allowed to include parameters, "definable" means "definable with parameters," all structures are infinite, and all languages are finite.*

---

Kuratowski's definition of an ordered pair in terms of set membership shows more broadly that we can always, in a definable way, turn an unordered pairing function into an ordered pairing function. Going the other way is more difficult; I'm interested in when it is possible.

Given a structure $\mathcal{X}$ in a language $\Sigma$ and a binary function symbol $F\not\in\Sigma$, say that $\mathcal{X}$ is **symmetrizable** iff there is a $\Sigma\sqcup\{F\}$-formula $\varphi(x,y,z)$ such that whenever $\mathcal{X}'$ is an expansion of $\mathcal{X}$ gotten by interpreting $F$ as an injection $X^2\rightarrow X$, the relation $G:=\varphi^{\mathcal{X}'}$ satisfies the following conditions:

- For each $a,b\in\mathcal{X}$ there is exactly one $c\in\mathcal{X}$ such that $G(a,b,c)$ holds. (So $G$ is the graph of a function.)
- For all $a,b,a',b',u\in\mathcal{X}$ we have $G(a,b,u)\wedge G(a',b',u)\implies (a,b)=(a',b')$ or $(a,b)=(b',a')$.
- For all $a,b,c\in\mathcal{X}$ we have $G(a,b,c)\iff G(b,a,c)$.

Basically, $\mathcal{X}$ is symmetrizable iff **ordered pairing functions on $\mathcal{X}$ can be definably turned into unordered pairing functions on $\mathcal{X}$**. There are two obvious types of symmetrizable structures:

- If $\mathcal{X}$ already has a definable unordered pairing function, then $\mathcal{X}$ is trivially symmetrizable.
- A bit more interestingly, if $\mathcal{X}$ has a definable linear order $\triangleleft$ then $\mathcal{X}$ is symmetrizable, via $\varphi(x,y,z)\equiv (x\triangleleft y\wedge F(x,y)=z)\vee(\neg x\triangleleft y\wedge F(y,x)=z)$.

In fact, the second example class doesn't need linear orders as such, but merely *tournaments*. A tournament on a set $X$ is a function $t:X^2\rightarrow X$ such that $t(a,b)=t(b,a)\in\{a,b\}$ for all $a,b\in X$; if $\mathcal{X}$ has a definable tournament, then $\mathcal{X}$ is symmetrizable.

I'm curious whether this is all that there is (I suspect not!).

> **Question**: Is there a symmetrizable structure with no definable tournament and no definable unordered pairing function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M = (\{0,1,2\} \times \mathbb{Q}, \triangleleft)$, where $(n,r) \triangleleft (m,s)$ if and only if $r < s$. We'll write $x \equiv y$ to mean $\neg x \triangleleft y \wedge \neg y \triangleleft x$. This is clearly an equivalence relation.

$M$ does not have any tournaments. Given some definable function $f(x,y)$, find an $\equiv$-class $X$ greater than any of the parameters of $f$. The automorphism group of $M$ is transitive on this set, so $f(x,y) = x$ implies $f(y,x)=y$, which is a contradiction.

It is possible to show that $M$ does not have an unordered pairing function, but it is somewhat tedious to write out a complete argument. Essentially you can show that any definable binary function $H(x,y)$ is piecewise equal to either $x$, $y$, or one of $H$'s parameters away from the $\equiv$-diagonal (and it's not too hard to characterize what can happen on the $\equiv$-diagonal for that matter). Furthermore, there must be a 'rectangle' on which one of these cases occurs everywhere. This will clearly always fail to be an unordered pairing function.

Now we'll show that $M$ is symmetrizable. Fix $3$ distinct parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$. Let $F:M^2\to M$ be an injection. I will describe an unordered pairing function $G:M^2 \to M$ which will clearly be $\{a,b,c\}$-definable using $F$. Given $x$ and $y$, consider the set $$A(x,y) = \{F(x,y),F(y,x),F(F(x,y),F(x,y)),F(F(y,x),F(y,x))\}.$$
Note that $A(x,y) = A(y,x)$. Since our $G(x,y)$ will really be a function of $A(x,y)$, we have that $G(x,y) = G(y,x)$.

If $x = y$, let $G(x,y) = F(F(x,x),a) = F(F(y,y),a)$. Assuming that $x\neq y$, note that we cannot have $|A(x,y)|<4$ (because $F(x,y) \neq F(z,z)$ for any $z$, and $F(F(x,y),F(x,y)) \neq F(F(y,x),F(y,x))$).

Let $B(x,y)\subseteq A(x,y)$ be the $\triangleleft$-least $\equiv$-class of $A(x,y)$.

- If $B(x,y) = \{F(z,w)\}$ for $z,w \in \{x,y\}$, let $G(x,y) = F(F(z,w),a)$.
- If $B(x,y) = \{F(F(z,w),F(z,w))\}$ for $z,w \in \{x,y\}$, let $G(x,y) = F(F(z,w),a)$.
- If $B(x,y) = \{F(x,y),F(y,x)\}$, let $G(x,y) = F(z,b)$, where $z$ is the third element of the full $\equiv$-class extending $B(x,y)$. (This will exist since $x\neq y$ and $F(x,y)$ is injective.)
- If $B(x,y) = \{F(F(x,y),F(x,y)),F(F(y,x),F(y,x))\}$, let $G(x,y) = F(z,c)$, where $z$ is the third element of the full $\equiv$-class extending $B(x,y)$. (This will exist since $F(x,y) \neq F(y,x)$.)
- If $B(x,y) = \{F(x,y),F(y,x),F(F(z,w),F(z,w))\}$ for $z,w \in \{x,y\}$, let $G(x,y) = F(F(z,w),a)$.
- If $B(x,y) = \{F(z,w),F(F(x,y),F(x,y)),F(F(y,x),F(y,x))\}$ for $z,w \in \{x,y\}$, let $G(x,y) = F(F(z,w),a)$.

Finally note that $B(x,y) = A(x,y)$ cannot happen.

To see that this is in fact an unordered pairing function, we have that $G(x,y)=u$ for some $y$ if and only if

- $u = F(z,a)$ and $x$ is one of the $F$-coordinates of $z$,
- $u = F(z,b)$ and $x$ is one of the $F$-coordinates of either of the other two elements of the $\equiv$-class of $z$, or
- $u = F(z,c)$ and $x$ is one of the $F$-coordinates of either of the $F$-coordinates of either of the other two elements of the $\equiv$-class of $z$.

Comment: Nice! I guess the natural follow-up question is whether nontrivially symmetrizable structures must *interpret* a nontrivial tournament, but that's not too natural and probably quite hard to attack.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Does the 'generic choice function on sets of 4 elements' interpret an infinite tournament?

Comment: No idea, offhand. (Sorry for the late reply, I missed this initially!)

Comment: Incidentally, I find myself asking *another* "are-tournaments-necessary?"-type question: [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424136/pairs-vs-two-pieces-is-the-usual-proof-model-theoretically-optimal). At a glance I don't think that the same sort of idea will work, but maybe you see a way to get it?